# How do I use a conditional array with more than one condition to calculate percentiles?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, array, finance

I have a table in excel with the following data:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Contribution Type | % Contribution Match | % Salary |
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
| Type 1            |                  0.5 |          |
| Type 1            |                  0.6 |          |
| Type 1            |                      |          |
| Type 2            |                      |     0.03 |
| Type 2            |                      |     0.04 |
| Type 2            |                      |        0 |
| Type 3            |                  0.7 |     0.05 |
| Type 3            |                  0.6 |     0.04 |
| Type 3            |                      |     0.05 |
| Type 1            |                  0.5 |          |
| Type 2            |                      |     0.04 |
| Type 3            |                 0.75 |      0.1 |
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

I would like to use an array formula to calculate quartiles for each contribution type based on the *additional condition* (because contribution type is the first condition) that the relevant data values are not left blank or entered in as zero value.

Type 1 matches 100% of salary up to a certain percent (X) of the employees contribution:

> {=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type
>   1",Contributions[% Contribution Match]),0.25)} (etc.for med, avg, and
>   75th)

Type 2 matches a limited percent (Y) of salary, with no limit on the employee's contribution:

> {=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type
>   2",Contributions[% Salary]),0.25)}(etc.for med, avg, and 75th)

Type 3 has limits on both the employee contribution and the salary percents:

> {=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type
>   3",Contributions[% Contribution Match]),0.25)} (etc.for med, avg, and
>   75th)
>
> {=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type
>   3",Contributions[% Salary]),0.25)} (etc.for med, avg, and 75th)

The resulting table calculates quartiles *including* blank and zero values (not what I want):

```
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+
|         Percentage of Employee Contribution        |            Percentage of Salary           |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+
|        | 25th %-ile| Median | Average | 75th %-ile | 25th %-ile| Median | Average | 75th %-ile |
| Type 1 | 12.50%    | 50.00% | 40.00%  | 57.50%     | 0.00%     | 0.00%  | 0.00%   | 0.00%      |
| Type 2 | 0.00%     | 0.00%  | 0.00%   | 0.00%      | 0.75%     | 3.50%  | 2.75%   | 4.00%      |
| Type 3 | 15.00%    | 65.00% | 51.25%  | 73.75%     | 4.25%     | 5.00%  | 6.00%   | 8.75%      |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+
```

I have tried every combination of IF(AND IF(IF I can think of. I am relatively new to using array formulas, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am open to using a different formula if there is a better one, but discouraged from reformatting the data table to presort values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may apply this Array Formula:*

```
{=PERCENTILE(IF((($A$2:$A$100=$F$3)*($B$2:$B$100=$G$3)),$C$2:$C$100),0.5)}
```

**N.B.**

1. In Cell `F3` & `G3` you have to store 
   Criterion, which makes Formula Dynamic rather 
   than Hard Core.
2. Finish Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
3. Adjust Cell references in Formula as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I wasn't sure how to store the criterion "<>0" in a separate cell, so I ended up hard coding them into the formulas. Do you know if there is, in fact, a way to store "not equal to zero" dynamically?

Comment: @SuziLmrdo, glad to help you ,,, put any value is not ZERO is the cell and use the Cell address <>$A$3. Keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [Rajesh S](https://superuser.com/users/711214/rajesh-s) for his assistance with my question! Here are the formulas I came up with, based on his advice:

Percentage of Employee Contribution - 25th Percentile (replace 0.25 with 0.75 to calculate 75th percentile)

> {=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 1")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match]),0.25),"N/A")}
>   {=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 2")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match]),0.25),"N/A")}
>   {=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 3")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match]),0.25),"N/A")}

Percentage of Employee Contribution - Median (replace MEDIAN with AVERAGE to calculate average values)

> {=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 1")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match])),"N/A")}
>   {=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 2")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match])),"N/A")}
>   {=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(((Contributions[Contribution Type]="Type 3")*(Contributions[% Contribution Match]<>0)),Contributions[% Contribution Match])),"N/A")}

To calculate Percentage of Salary - 25th, Median, Average, 75th - replace all instances of "% Contribution Match" in the above formulas with "% of Salary"